# Is salesforce DX for me?

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, deployment-api

i am trying to implement a Continuous Integration and hence Continuous Delivery with salesforce. I have made good in-roads using the ANT migration tool, CI server and an open source nodejs package. 
We don't build apps, we are an org that mostly deals with the "Opportunity" app. And from what i have seen, the major dev work (as they consider) in the configuration changes (apart from some minor apex classes, vf pages etc).

Now, i am reading a lot about salesforceDX. And with the lack of proper salesforce background, i am not able to fully decide if this is for us (can we use DX for the CI CD, rather than the custom forged tool chain?). Some of my interactions so far, kind of tells me that DX is for firms that builds salesforce App in marketplace.

How far is this true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer the following question:

> Do you move code or configuration from one org to another?

If you answered yes, Salesforce DX is for you. While it does have a bunch of nifty features for ISV developers, it also has a lot of features for any organization that wants to use CI, code versioning systems (CVS), proper QA testing, UAT, etc.

That said, if you have something that already works, you don't *need* DX. It's simply a tool provided by Salesforce to simplify development. You can choose to use DX, or you can choose to use another system. Both solutions are equally acceptable.

If you're looking to simplify the current process, DX can probably help you do that. It's very easy to get started, and you can migrate the source from an existing structure you may already have (including Force.com IDE, MavensMate, etc). It integrates nicely with Heroku Pipelines for CI and Git for CVS, or you can replace those parts with tools of your choice.

DX is not a single tool in and of itself, it's a suite of tools designed to work together to get started quickly, with minimal changes to existing processes.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I am trying to compare salesforceDX with what i have now. And that way, i can measure the efforts required for maintaining and supporting the solutions. Finally is SFdx a paid feature from salesforce (i know they seem to be offering trials), what if we want to adopt it ?

Comment: @OK999 If you have a subscription to salesforce (e.g. Enterprise Edition), DX comes with your subscription. The free trial mode is for those that want to try it out before they subscribe to Salesforce.